# How to remove revmob fullscreen ad without press any x button issue

Tags: android, revmobads

I have successfully integrate RevMob full screen Ads

I used full screen ad in a different way for example :

when user press play button the full screen ad appears and after 5 sec. it will disappear automatically and redirect to the game.

I have done 5 sec. wait to display ad, after that **i want to remove ad without any click event**, i don't know how it is possible..?

I have already used hide() method but not working.

Comment: how do you add the ad? if this is a view then try removeView, if the is a dialog try cancel

Comment: In Revmob fullscreen ad there is no view used, i used fullscreenAd.show() method to show fullscreen Ad but for dismiss they didn't provide any cancel() or dismiss() method. so without those methods how can i remove ad?

Answer (score 0):

As describe on RevMob Documentation [site](http://sdk.revmob.com/api/android/com/revmob/ads/fullscreen/RevMobFullscreen.html):

```
hide() 
Hide the ad - If it is not loaded, it will not be automatically show after it is loaded.
```

If hide() is not working maybe there is a bug on the SDK, which version are you using?
I recommend you to contact the sdk guys (sdk@revmob.com).

Comment: When they answer let us know.

Comment: i get the response from Revmob and they said it's bug in hide() method :(

Comment: anybody got any luck hiding revmob full sceen programatically. my problem is when network speed is throttled it show when user is playing next game and its frustrating.